# Pass Ajax Response to php variable

Tags: jquery

I am unable to pass ajax response data to view. the view do not get passed data. shows nothing for registernumberP. please help me. Thanks

**AJAX Response:**

```js
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "studentId": "16",
    }
]
```

**AJAX Call:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/Payments/GetStudentPaymentDetails",
    data: {
        studentId: studentId
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#registernumberP').val(data['studentId']);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Some error occurred!');
    },
});
```

**View :**

```php
<?php 
    $data = array(
        'id'   => 'registernumberP',
        'name' => 'registernumberP'
    );
    echo form_input($data);
?> 
</div>
```

Comment: We can help you when your code makes sense, or when you post a coherent explanation. That's no sense. What's the view? What's the ajax response? What you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#registernumberP').val(data['studentId']);
```

Should be

```
$('#registernumberP').val(data[0]studentId);
```

And `data` can be removed :

```
data: {
    studentId: studentId
},
```